# Hide Recyclerview child apart from the one i clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing a horizontal recyclerview whit Pierfrancesco Soffritti's YouTubePlayerView to show a series of video.
I added a fullscreen listener to go full screen when i click the button.
What i was trying to do is to hide all the recyclerview child when going fullscreen apart the clicked one, and then restore the views when exiting fullscreen.
Is it possible in some way?
Thank you in advance

EDITED

This is my Adapter class, I would like to select, in the OnBind, the Recyclerview item I clicked on and hide it

public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoAdapter";

```
private List<Video> mVideos;
private Lifecycle mLifecycle;


public VideoAdapter(List<Video> mVideos, Lifecycle mLifecycle) {
    this.mVideos = mVideos;
    this.mLifecycle = mLifecycle;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_videos, parent, false);
    mLifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView);

    return new ViewHolder(youTubePlayerView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.cueVideo(mVideos.get(position).getVideoId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(!(mVideos == null))
        return mVideos.size();
    return 0;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private String currentVideoId;

    ViewHolder(YouTubePlayerView playerView) {
        super(playerView);
        youTubePlayerView = playerView;
        youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer initializedYouTubePlayer) {
                youTubePlayer = initializedYouTubePlayer;
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(currentVideoId, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    void cueVideo(String videoId) {
        currentVideoId = videoId;

        if(youTubePlayer == null)
            return;

        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you try adding some code to show what you have already done?

Comment: hi Cristi, i edited my post. Thank you

Comment: It'll be hard to do that, and also difficult to maintain... I suggest you to add a listener with a callback that takes the information of the clicked row from the adapter; and that listener can open some fragment/View on top of the `RecyclerView`; or even you can hide the `RecyclerView`

Comment: yeah i basically quit ahah

Answer (score 0):

I am not using RecyclerView, but I was solving (and solved) a similar issue in my app using LinearLayout - now I modified my **code just for the purpose of YT fullscreen** (consider it as a "fake" fullscreen" - you are rotating the whole layout while remaining in portrait mode :-) ).

In a nutshell:

- create a layout for fullscreen and add it to the parent layout;
- in the `.getPlayerUiController().setFullScreenButtonClickListener` remove the YT player View from the layout (eg. `trailerLayout`) and add the same YT player View into the fullscreen layout;
- when exiting fullscreen, remove the YT player View from the fullscreen layout and add the same YT player View into the `trailerLayout`.

And except for fullscreen, I also added a few lines of code to override the behavior of the back button, so it will

- not quit the app, but only move the app to the background
- while in fullscreen exit the fullscreen.

Here is the code, I hope it will help :-)

- **activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/trailer">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

- **MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.graphics.Rect
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        this?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(
                this,
                object : OnBackPressedCallback(
                        true
                ) {
                    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                        moveTaskToBack(true)
                    }
                })

        val trailerLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.trailer)
        val fullScreenLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.fullscreen)

        val youTubeButton = Button(this)
        youTubeButton.text = "Load YT video"
        trailerLayout.addView(youTubeButton)

        youTubeButton.setOnClickListener {
            val rectangle = Rect()
            val window: Window = window
            window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle)
            val statusBarHeight: Int = rectangle.top
            val sizeFullscreen = statusBarHeight + supportActionBar!!.height

            val fullScreenYouTubeTrailerLayout = LinearLayout(this)
            fullScreenYouTubeTrailerLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            fullScreenYouTubeTrailerLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

            val youTubeTrailerView = YouTubePlayerView(this)
            youTubeTrailerView.getPlayerUiController().showFullscreenButton(true)
            lifecycle.addObserver(youTubeTrailerView)
            youTubeTrailerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                    val videoId = "VppjX4to9s4"
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0f)
                }
            })
            trailerLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout()
            trailerLayout.addView(youTubeButton)
            trailerLayout.addView(youTubeTrailerView)
            fullScreenLayout.addView(fullScreenYouTubeTrailerLayout)

            this?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(
                    this,
                    object : OnBackPressedCallback(
                            true
                    ) {
                        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                            if (window.decorView.systemUiVisibility ==
                                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            ) {
                                val w = fullScreenLayout.width - sizeFullscreen
                                val h = fullScreenLayout.height
                                fullScreenLayout.rotation = 0f
                                fullScreenLayout.translationX = 0f
                                fullScreenLayout.translationY = 0f
                                val lp = fullScreenLayout.layoutParams as ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                                lp.height = w
                                lp.width = h
                                
                                fullScreenLayout.requestLayout()
                                fullScreenYouTubeTrailerLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout()
                                trailerLayout.addView(youTubeButton)
                                trailerLayout.addView(youTubeTrailerView)
                                youTubeTrailerView.exitFullScreen()
                                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
                                window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.VISIBLE
                                window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
                                supportActionBar?.show()

                            } else moveTaskToBack(true)
                        }
                    })

            youTubeTrailerView.getPlayerUiController().setFullScreenButtonClickListener {
                fullScreenYouTubeTrailerLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        )
                if (youTubeTrailerView.isFullScreen()) {
                    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
                    actionBar?.show()
                    supportActionBar?.show()
                    val w = fullScreenLayout.width - sizeFullscreen
                    val h = fullScreenLayout.height
                    fullScreenLayout.rotation = 0f
                    fullScreenLayout.translationX = 0f
                    fullScreenLayout.translationY = 0f
                    val lp = fullScreenLayout.layoutParams as ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                    lp.height = w
                    lp.width = h
                    
                    fullScreenLayout.requestLayout()
                    fullScreenYouTubeTrailerLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout()
                    trailerLayout.addView(youTubeButton)
                    trailerLayout.addView(youTubeTrailerView)
                    youTubeTrailerView.exitFullScreen()
                    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.VISIBLE
                    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
                } else {
                    window.setFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    )
                    window.addFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    )

                    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

                    actionBar?.hide()
                    supportActionBar?.hide()

                    val w = fullScreenLayout.width
                    val h = fullScreenLayout.height + sizeFullscreen
                    fullScreenLayout.rotation = 90f
                    fullScreenLayout.translationX = (w - h) / 2.toFloat()
                    fullScreenLayout.translationY = (h - w) / 2.toFloat()
                    val lp = fullScreenLayout.layoutParams as ViewGroup.LayoutParams
                    lp.height = w
                    lp.width = h
                    
                    fullScreenLayout.requestLayout()
                    trailerLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout()
                    fullScreenYouTubeTrailerLayout.addView(youTubeTrailerView)
                    youTubeTrailerView.enterFullScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a "screenOrientation="portrait" in the

- **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
...
```

and for newcomers, don´t forget to implement the YT library in the

- **build.gradle (:app)**

```
...
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
...
}
...
```